# Good set principle (Appropriate set principle) in generic class

Tags: measure-theory

I've seen in many books this principle as that:

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a collection of subsets of X and $\mathscr{C}: =\{B \in \sigma(A): \text{$B$ is a good set (or has a specific property) }\} $.

If $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\sigma(\mathscr{A}) \subset \mathscr{C}$ .

However I've been studying by Shiryaev (Probability-1, 2016) and he applies that principle to more generic contexts (for example, for monotonic class, not necessarily $\sigma$-algebra). I still don't understand why can he do that. He is using the same principle for things which are not $\sigma$-algebra.

Does anyone know a reference with this generalized principle explained (good set principle in non $\sigma$-algebra contexts)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMpYH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcu5M.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the principle holds true for sigma algebras is that $\sigma(\mathscr A)$ is defined to be the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathscr A$, so if $\mathscr C$ is another sigma algebra containing $\mathscr A$ then $\sigma(\mathscr A) \subseteq \mathscr C$ by definition.

In the other contexts in the images you linked, it appears he is doing the same thing.  For example, $\mathscr M$ is defined to be the smallest monotone class containing $\mathscr A$, so if $\tilde{\mathscr M}$ is another monotone class containing $\mathscr A$ then $\mathscr M \subseteq \tilde{\mathscr M}$ by the definition of $\mathscr M$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply! Maybe the thing that is still confuse for me is: what would be the "smallest monotone class containing $\mathscr{A}$"? Maybe the generalized idea of "the smallest class" of any kind, because I've always associated that with $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: It would mean the same thing as it does for $\sigma$-algebras: "$\mathscr M$ is the smallest monotone class containing $\mathscr A$" means that $\mathscr A \subseteq \mathscr M$, $\mathscr M$ is a monotone class, and if $\mathscr N$ is another monotone class containing $\mathscr A$ then $\mathscr M \subseteq \mathscr N$.